# to verify a relation involving conditional probability with an example

Tags: probability

we have a relation P(A/complement(B)) = (P(A) - P(A/B)P(B))/(1-P(B)). This equation satisfies for A and B except P(B)=1.
If X,Z are independent exponential RV with parameter $\lambda$1 = 1/10.39 $\lambda$2 = 1/6.195 respectively. If A denotes the event (max(X,Z)>=14) and B denotes event (X>=Z).

P(A) = P(max(X,Z)>=14)
= 1-P(max(X,Z)<14)=1-P(X<14,Z<14)=$1-((1-\exp(-14/10.39))(1-\exp(-14/6.195)))$
=.3371
$P(B) = P(X>=Z)= 1-P(X<Z)=\int_{x=0}^{Infinity}\int_{z=x}^{Infinity}((1/10.39)(1/6.195)(\exp(-x/10.39))(\exp(-z/6.195)) dz dx)$=.62636
P(A/B) = P(max(X,Z)>=14/X>=Z)= 1-P(max(X,Z)<14/X>=Z)=1-P(X<14,Z<14/X>=Z)
=$1-\int_{x=0}^{14}\int_{z=0}^{x}((1/10.39)(1/6.195)(\exp(-x/10.39))(\exp(-z/6.195)) dz dx)$=.6233
$P(A/complement(B))=P(max(X,Z)>=14/X<Z)= 1-P(max(X,Z)<14/X<Z)=1-P(X<14,Z<14/X<Z)=1-\int_{x=0}^{14}\int_{z=x}^{14}((1/10.39)(1/6.195)(\exp(-x/10.39))(\exp(-z/6.195)) dz dx)=.71384$
With all the four values I calculated. I am not able to satisfy the relation in the first line.This relation is found in a book.I feel I have done something wrong in calculation of p(A/B)Can anyone please help.Integrations I have done with the help of Mathematica.

Comment: I recommend fixing your typesetting. More people are going to read it if it's more legible.

Comment: Is the question: $P(\max(X,Z)\ge 14 \mid X<Z)=?$

Comment: yes .  with a  condition change . P(max(X,Z)≥14∣X>Z)

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is: $P(\max(X,Z)\ge 14 \mid X>Z)=?$

By the definition of the conditional probability we have

$$P(\max(X,Z)\ge 14 \mid X>Z)=\frac{P(\{\max(X,Z)\ge 14\}\cap\{ X>Z\})}{P(X>Z)}.$$

Then we have two probabilities to calculate:

**(1)** Notice that

$$P(\{\max(X,Z)\ge 14\}\cap\{ X>Z\})=P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ X>Z\})=$$
$$=P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ 14\le Z<X\})+P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ Z<14\})=$$
$$=P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ 14\le Z<X\})+P(X \ge 14)P( Z<14).$$

then
$$P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ 14\le Z<X\})=E[P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ 14\le Z<X\}\mid X)]=E[1_{\{X\ge14\}}P(14\le Z<X\mid X)]$$

and

$$P(14\le Z<X\mid X=x)=P(14\le Z<x)=\lambda_2\int_{14}^x e^{-\lambda_2z}\ dz=e^{-\lambda_2x}-e^{-\lambda_214}.$$

So,

$$P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ 14\le Z<X\})=P(X\ge 14)\left(e^{-\lambda_2x}-e^{-\lambda_214}\right)$$

where

$$P(X \ge 14)=\int_0^{14} \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1 x}\ dx=1-e^{\lambda_1 14}.$$

Finally

$$P(\{X \ge 14\}\cap\{ 14\le Z<X\})=(1-e^{\lambda_1 14})(e^{-\lambda_2x}-e^{-\lambda_214}).$$

**(2)** As far as

$$P(X>Z)=E[P(X>Z\mid X)]$$

we have

$$P(X>Z\mid X=x)=P(x>Z)=\int_0^x \lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2z}\ dz=1-e^{-\lambda_2x}$$

and, finally
$$P(X>Z)=\int_0^{\infty} \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1x}(1-e^{-\lambda_2x}) \ dx=...$$

**EDITED 1**

The suggested solution (by the OP) considers the double integral first:

$$P(B)=P(X\ge Z)=1-P(X<Z)=1-\iint_S f_{X,Z}(x,z)\ dxdz$$

where

$$f_{X,Z}(x,y)=\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2z)}$$

and

$$S=\{(x,z):x< z\}$$

as shown in the figure below:

[image]

With this

$$\iint_S f_{X,Z}(x,z)\ dxdz=\lambda_1\lambda_2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda_1x}\left[\int_x^{\infty} e^{-\lambda_2z}\ dz\right] \  dx=$$
$$=\lambda_1\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x }\ dx=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\approx 0.373.$$

So,

$$P(B)\approx 1-0.373=0.627. $$

The first numerical result seems to be OK. But I could not understand the way you wrote up the corresponding integral.

**EDITED 2**

As far as

$$P(A\mid B)=1-P(\overline A \mid B)=1-P(\max(X,Z)<14 \mid X\ge Z)=$$
$$=1-\frac{P(\{X<14\}\cap\{Z<14\}\cap\{X\ge Z\})}{P(X\ge Z)}.$$

Then

$$P(\{X<14\}\cap\{Z<14\}\cap\{X\ge Z\})=\lambda_1\lambda_2\iint_{S'}\ e^{-(\lambda_1x+\lambda_2z)}dx dz$$

where

$$S'=\{(x,z):x<14,y<14, x\ge z\}.$$

So,

$$P(\{X<14\}\cap\{Z<14\}\cap\{X\ge Z\})=\lambda_1\lambda_2\int_0^{14}e^{-\lambda_1 x}\left[\int_0^x e^{-\lambda_2 z}\ dz\right] \ dx=$$
$$=\lambda_1 \int_0^{14} e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x }\ dx=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}(1-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)14 })\approx $$
$$\approx 0.373\cdot (1-e^{-3.61
})=0.373\cdot 0.973=0.363.$$

Finally,

$$P(A\mid B) = 1-\frac{P(\overline A \cap B)}{P(B)}\approx 1-\frac{0.363}{0.627}\approx 0.421.$$

This is what I've manage to get. It's your turn now.

Comment: can we not do this using double integral finding the limits according to the condition and evaluate the integrals as I have tried above.Is there something wrong?

Comment: I will take a closer look. But, to be honest, if the post is not professionally edited then the visitors have less desire to scrutinize it. (Take this personally : )

Comment: Sorry for inconvienience.I am new to this. I will learn to post it professionally edited

Comment: No problemo. I've tried to compute the first integral the way you did.

Comment: Thanks Again. I am able to get P(A) and P(B) Numerically. Can u check the double integral of P(A/B).? Please. And for P(A and B) depends on X as shown by you above. does it  not have numerical value for a given exponential parameters.?

Comment: @ramanan: I Checked the second part. Please, you check my result now.

Comment: Thanks very much .I got every thing cleared. You have done a big favour to me.

Comment: Everything is clear now. thanks very much

Comment: If you liked my solution would you please press the check mark button?

Comment: could I know where is the check mark button. So that I  can press

Comment: On the upper left hand side of the answer there is an upward pointing arrow, a downward pointing arrow and a check mark. If you click the upward arrow then you express that you like an answer, if you click on the downward arrow then you express that you don't like an answer if you click on the check mark then you express that you acept an answer.

Comment: I clicked the upper arrow mark